# R igraph: algoritm to find the hierachy between certain edges in a DAG

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I have a directed graph (DAG) representing a river network. On some of the rivers (edges) there are flow gauging stations. I would like to rank these stations according to their hierarchy from the most upstream river segments. The most upstream stations will have a class 1. Stations with only 1 station rank upstream will have a class 2, stations with 2 station ranks upstream will have a class 3, and so on. Is there an algorithm in igraph to do that? I searched in the doc for terms like "rank", "hierarchy", "order" but didn't find anything resembling to what I would like to perform.

I also used "distances" from the most downstream edge (the outlet of the river network) for the classification but it does not account for the relations among the stations (edges with very different distances can have the same rank depending on the river network configuration)...

Any suggestion on a graph algorithm to do that?

Here is an illustration of the classification:

[image]

Here is the data I use for testing (NOT related to the picture):

```
library(igraph)

vertices_df <- data.frame(
  id = c(418,410,402,394,386,427,378,370,362,354,346,338,330,322,314,306,298,290,282,274,595,266,419,395,258,250,242,234,226,218,210,202,194,186,178,170,162,146,138,130,122,114,106,98,90,82,74,66,58,50,42,34,26,18,10,2,587,579,571,563,555,547,539,531,523,515,28,12,154,507,499,491,483,475,467,459,451,443,435,411,403,387,379,371,363,355,347,339,331,323,315,307,299,291,283,275,267,259,251,243,235,227,219,211,203,195,187,179,171,163,155,147,139,131,123,115,107,99,91,83,75,67,59,51,43,35,27,19,11,3,20,4),
  station = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
)

edges_df <- data.frame(
  from = c(410,402,394,378,427,403,370,362,354,346,338,330,322,314,306,298,290,282,274,595,587,395,107,3,250,218,226,26,58,66,146,34,18,98,106,74,130,507,571,563,443,547,539,531,523,515,28,20,499,491,483,475,467,459,451,435,411,355,387,379,347,371,331,307,195,291,115,147,171,43,99,123,227,259,27,2,234,10,386,419,194,202,186,122,170,162,258,178,266,242,114,210,154,11,75,90,42,82,50,138,579,67,323,555,179,211,243,219,267,12,4,35,315,363,19,299,51,187,91,155,275,163,339,203,283,131,139,59,83,235,251),
  to = c(418,410,402,394,386,427,378,370,362,354,346,338,330,322,314,306,298,290,282,274,595,266,419,395,258,250,242,234,226,218,210,202,194,186,178,170,162,587,579,571,563,555,547,539,531,523,515,28,507,499,491,483,475,467,459,451,443,435,411,403,387,379,371,363,355,347,339,331,323,315,307,299,291,283,275,418,410,402,394,386,370,362,354,346,338,330,322,314,306,298,282,274,595,419,395,250,234,226,218,210,587,579,571,563,555,547,539,531,523,515,28,507,491,483,467,459,451,443,435,411,403,387,379,355,347,331,323,307,299,291,283)
)

net <- graph.data.frame(
  edges_df[, c("from", "to")],
  directed=TRUE,
  vertices=vertices_df
)
```

So I know edges 418, 394, 386, 499, 355, 331, 35 have a stations and I would like to rank them with an attribute 1, 2, 3, 4...

After having tried the "distances" and "topo_sort" algo in igraph, my last attempt was to use dfs:

```
res <- dfs(
  net,
  root = "418",
  neimode = "in",
  unreachable = TRUE,
  order = TRUE,
  order.out = TRUE,
  father = TRUE,
  dist = TRUE
)

res$dist[names(res$dist) %in% as.character(vertices_df[vertices_df$station == 1, "id"])]
```

So I know the order of the edges from the most downstream edge but I lost the relation information among the upstream edges (edges with different distances can have the same rank). I'm not sure where it leads me so I was wondering if another graph algorithm would better fit the purpose...

I would use R preferably as other parts of the workflow is in that language...

Comment: Please share a reproducible example

Comment: Can you please provide (1) a small illustration explaining the problem and the expected output; whiteboard photo is perfect (2) _small_ example data in whatever format.

Comment: Also let us know what programming language you are using igraph from.

Comment: It looks like you basically want the Strahler number, except only for the stations, not other parts of the graph. Correct? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number

Comment: It looks like it but the problem is that the stations can located anywhere in the network so  two stations with ranks e.g. 2 and 3 can be located on edges with Strahler numbers like 3 and 7. Also two stations with the same ranks can be on edges with different Strahler numbers...

Comment: I am not really an R expert, and I don't have time to figure out how to implement the following algorithm in R, but it should work. Maybe @ThomasIsCoding is up for it. First you do a DFS with mode `"in"` from the root, and record the vertex order according to `order.out` (root is last). Also record  the parent vector (`father`). Just like in your post. Now you initialize a "rank" vector to all `1`s, iterate through the vertices according to `order.out`, and compare the "rank" of each vertex to its parent.

Comment: If the parent rank is smaller than the child, then: (1) if the parent is a station, set its rank to one larger than the child (2) if the parent is not a station, set its rank to the same as the child.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try it

Comment: There are two mistakes in my proposal: (1) the station ranks will start at 2 this way, not 1. Initialize the rank vector to zeros instead (2) make sure that no leaves of the tree are stations. If they are, add an additional dummy node. Hopefully this fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
# subset vertices of interest, i.e., `station == 1`
v <- as.character(with(vertices_df, id[station == 1]))

# find the sink node among `v`
snk <- v[which(colSums(distances(net, v, v, "out") == Inf) == 0)]

# find the paths to the sink node from all other nodes and assign ranks along the path
lst <- lapply(
  v[!v %in% snk],
  function(p) {
    s <- intersect(names(shortest_paths(net, p, snk)$vpath[[1]]), v)
    data.frame(id = s, vrank = seq_along(s))
  }
)

# aggreagte all info and take the max rank for each id
dfout <- aggregate(. ~ id, do.call(rbind, lst), max)
```

and you will see

```
> dfout
   id vrank
1 331     1
2  35     1
3 355     1
4 386     2
5 394     3
6 418     4
7 499     2
```

Comment: It works great! Thanks a lot!